# When repetitions in the selection of the objects are allowed, the no. of ways of selecting 'r' objects from 'n' distinct objects is $C(n+r-1,r)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How to show that : When repetitions in the selection of the objects are allowed, the no. of ways of selecting $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects is $C(n+r-1,r)$.

**EDIT** It's also known as "Stars and Bars" proof in Probability.(My question closely follows this concept but both are different tasks).

I need **hint/ resource** recommendation, please. (This may be a duplicate question but I didn't find any satisfactory answer on my side).

Comment: I don’t think this is true, unless I’m misunderstanding what you are asking. As I read it, this should be $n^r.$

Comment: I'm not mistaking in writing so, it may be assumed that it's true. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's true if order doesn't matter.

Comment: Is anywhere a concrete mathematical proof available for this identity? In any books or so? @EspeciallyLime

Comment: @MICKEY I've added an answer.

Comment: See my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473862/how-is-the-formula-for-counting-multisets-derived/2475331#2475331).

Answer (score 2):

Stars and Bars occurs whenever you want to count the number of ways to group identical objects. Let's say we have $n$ objects, and we want to divide them into $r $ groups, so that each group can have zero or more objects. This problem can also we said as follows -

We have $n$ stars and $r - 1$ bars and we want to arrange them in a row. (Each arrangement represents a way in which the objects can be divided). Now since $n$ objects are similar of one kind, and $r - 1$ objects are similar of another kind, The number of permutations will be - $$\dfrac{(n + r - 1)!}{n\,!(r - 1)\,!}
$$. Which is equivalent to $C(n+r-1,n)$

Comment: Can you please explain how did you get $(n + r - 1)!$? @devkrishnasadana

Comment: Since the total number of objects to be arranged are $(n + r - 1)$, out of which $n$ are stars and $(r - 1)$ are bars.

Comment: But, your result is different than the desired one. It should be $C(n+r-1,r)$ instead of $C(n+r-1,n)$. @devkrishnasadana

Comment: The result I wrote is the same as in [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) problem.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is as follows. If we have $a$ copies of the first object, $b$ of the second and so on, we can represent this visually as follows:
$$\underbrace{*\cdots*}_\limits{a\text{ stars}}\bigg|\underbrace{*\cdots*}_\limits{b\text{ stars}}\bigg|\cdots\quad\cdots\bigg|**$$
i.e. the bars divide the line into spaces representing the $n$ objects, and the stars in each space (possibly none) represent how many copies of that object you have. So how many stars and how many bars do you have in this representation?

This method is known as "[stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))".

Comment: @MICKEY Also ask: do all the representations correspond to a selection? Do any pair of distinct representations correspond to distinct selections (i.e. can I make sure different selections have different representations)? Did I find all selections via these representations? $$\ $$Basically, if you had a function $f: \{ selections\} \to \{ representations\}$ as described above would it be well-defined, injective and surjective?

Comment: Can you please do the further edit in the question, adding your opinions? @Steve

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking towards a more formal mathematical proof, there should be a proper mathematical proof of this theorem, if I'm not wrong. @EspeciallyLime

Comment: @MICKEY I am quite certain you can answer these without much help. I just intend to guide you through $\textbf{why}$ does this even work.

Comment: @MICEY and how to turn Especially Lime's proof into a more formal mathematical proof. He/she described a set of representations and a map $\{ selection \}\to \{representations\}$. You just need to show why that map is a valid bijection to find that both sets are of the same cardinality. Then $$|\{ selections \}| = |\{ representations \}|  = |\{ \text{$r$-subsets of an $n+r-1$ set} \}| = C(n+r-1,r)$$

Comment: @MICKEY this is (or can be made into) a formal mathematical proof : define a bijection between the choices for two different problems, and show that one of them is counted by the appropriate formula.